# Why is require('fs') causing my js variables to not show in html?

Tags: javascript, html, fs

I'm trying to make an electron app that increments and reduces a number and updates that number to a local .txt file.

I have the numbers displaying and counting up/down but as soon as I introduce the fs node it  reverts to the placeholder text of "ScoreA"

```
var fs = require('fs'); 

//Score A initialise
var scoreAOriginal = 0;
var dx = scoreAOriginal;

//Score A button functions
function incA(num){
  dx = dx + num;
}

function decA(num){
    if (dx >= 1){
     dx = dx - num; 
    }
}

//Score B initialise
var scoreBOriginal = 0;
var dy = scoreBOriginal;

//Score B button functions
function incB(num){
    dy = dy + num;
}

function decB(num){
    dy = dy - num;
}

// Refresher and value assignment to div classes in index.html
setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById("scoreA").innerHTML = dx; document.getElementById("scoreB").innerHTML = dy; }, 100);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Peppy - by Doug</title>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Peppy</h1>
      <div class="scoreConsoles">
        <div>
          <button class="button button5" onclick="incA(1)">+</button>
            <div id="scoreA">scoreA</div>
          <button class="button button5" onclick="decA(1)">-</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="button button5" onclick="incB(1)">+</button>
            <div id="scoreB">scoreB</div>
          <button class="button button5" onclick="decB(1)">-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: probably because `require` is not defined (in the browser; 'fs' is definitely not available in the browser) and the script stops with an Error.

Comment: Add the complete html code you have written

Comment: @Piyush , added full html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create the window? You know you need to enable node integration:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
```